# Symbian: Database use by the Symbian Mobile Phone

Tags: database, symbian, nokia

I have one task to create an application in which some data is there which I need to store in database of Symbian Device. Which database is used by the Symbian Mobile Phone. Or is there any other way to store data in these device.
I am new in Symbian, so where I get all these information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What versions of Symbian do you plan to support? If you plan to support older Symbian devices as well then better to go with Symbian native database. But if you plan to support only the newer touch devices (not the pointer touch ones), then you can check out sqlite3, which is included with the sdk.
More information can be sought on http://developer.nokia.com.

Answer (score 1):

Some Symbian applications, including some built-in ones, use [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: According to [the sqlite web site](http://www.sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html), "Newer versions of the SymbianOS have SQLite built in."